# How to make an animation in Geoserver or in Leaflet

Tags: html, animation, leaflet, geoserver

I have three shapefile and I would like to create an html animation in Geoserver or in Leaflet. 
I looked this guide in Geoserver https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/time.html#specifying-a-time and this one https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html but I didn't understand how can choose the time for everyone shapefile. 
Someone could help me?

Answer (score 2):

This is not how time dimensions work in GeoServer. You need to make one shapefile (or database table) with one or two date (or timestamp) columns. Then when you add that dataset to GeoServer you will be able to select the column(s) for the start (and end) of the time dimension in GeoServer.

[image]